# Want to do work on my Application Uninstall:android

Tags: android, events, uninstallation

i am aware of android BROADCAST_PACKAGE_REMOVED for notify when any application is uninstalling from device.

Now it is possible that when i uninstall one application and that application do some work before and uninstall.
e.g: my application work with android contact if application uninstall at that time i want to change in contact data.

can i get any event for uninstalling app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No.

(at least until the current version of Android)

In case it's any help, widgets do get notified when their last instance is removed. However, the app than contains the widget remains installed.